# How to permanently ignore grub-pc package for aptitude?

Tags: apt, grub, aptitude

I'm running Ubuntu 10.4 virtualized under Xen and the `grub-pc` package is broken and `apt-get` notifies me every time I run it.

I just want to configure apt-get / aptitude to ignore this package permanently.

How do I do this?

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up grub-pc (1.98-1ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'grub-pc hold' | dpkg --set-selections
```

or, through aptitude, you can mark the package as hold

However, since they are moving forward with grub2, you might take a look at the .postinst file to see why it is failing.

/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst

put   set -x    somewhere below their initial bits of code then do:

```
apt-get -f install
```

and post the error message reported.

also, post the output from

```
dpkg -l | grep grub
```

Comment: Thanks, I disabled it and modify the `.postinst` file to `exit 0`. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

`grub-common.postinst` and `grub-pc.postinst`

Delete everything below the third line so they both look like this:

```
!#/bin/bash
set -e
```